# Why is ~facelets.VIEW_STATE~ showing within my form

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

I have a rich panel that contains a form. This form is posted with javascript. What happens is that when doing the post the form rerenders but with ~facelets.VIEW_STATE~ at the bottom.
It seems that it is having trouble with rendering some facelet.
This is showing before the post instead of ~facelets.VIEW_STATE~:

```
<input type="hidden" value="j_id2" id="javax.faces.ViewState" name="javax.faces.ViewState">
```

Code snippet for template:

```
<rich:panel style="margin:0 15px">
     <h:form>
          <s:decorate template="craftsManTemplate.xhtml">
              <h:inputTextarea rows="3" cols="80" value="#{craftsManForm.description}" required="true"
                                     id="cmDescription"/>
                </s:decorate>
                <f:param name="craftsManForm" value="craftsManForm"/>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="postCraftsmanFormBtn"
                       style="border:none;margin:5px 0 20px;width:259px;background:transparent url(/img/buttons/btn_send_request.png) no-repeat 0 0;"
                       class="bigBtn"></a>


            </h:form>
        </rich:panel>
```

Do you have any idea why this is? Is it possible to suppress this or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out why, somehow :D the ajax form snook down and inside my cache tag.
This is of course not valid.

```
<s:cache region="myPageCache">
 ... 
</s:cache>
```